# What type of error is this in c#?

Tags: c#

In c# (or any language) accessing variable before it is being initialised,
what type of error is this?
A semantic error, syntactical or something else?

Example of the code that i had.

```
static string currencyConverterMenu =
        "\n" +
        "-Currency Converter-\n" +
        currencyConverterList +
        "0) Back to Main Menu\n";

static string currencyConverterList =
        "1) Australian dollar\n" +
        "2) United States dollar\n";

Console.WriteLine(currencyConverterMenu);
```

Comment: ...a runtime error (compile-time too in C#'s case).

Comment: It is a *highly probably runtime exception*, usually undefined behavior.

Comment: In many languages, it comes up as a compile-time error.

Comment: variable_name does not exist in the current context..

Comment: By my understanding, @crbon is asking for *C# compiler*, whether 'accessing variable before it is being initialized' is semantic error or syntactical error. By checking http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics, I think it semantic error.

Comment: @qxg Yeah thats exactly what I was meaning to ask

Comment: @SimonWhitehead if you look at the sample code, i does not produce a compile-time error, as i can compile and execute it.

Comment: Of course.. because you have initialized it...

Comment: @SimonWhitehead so in this case what is the error called. It prints the following '-Currency Converter- [breakline here] 0) Back to Main Menu'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax is about code rules like where to put semicolons, quotes of parenthesis.

Semantic is more about meaning and logic like what type of variable you must use or do you initialized it.

So it's semantic error.